# Timing actions with python

Tags: python

I am trying to time certain actions in apps like Excel, Power BI, Tableau, some Adobe apps, but I am having trouble getting the end time of an action. For example, copying cells from Excel and pasting them into PowerPoint or opening a workbook in Power BI or Tableau and waiting for the report/dashboard to fully render. Getting the start time is easy since I just get the time when I execute an action in the code, but finding a way to mark when that action finishes has been elusive.

I have started looking into processes and tasks to see if one ends when my action is over. I am using Process Monitor and recording to the screen to see if something happens when the action is over. There is possibly something there I can work with but I haven't been able to get the same level of detail as Process Monitor does with Python. Process Monitor shows the operation of a process/thread. Is there a way to get that in python (I have looked but haven't found it yet)?

Barring that, does anyone have a suggestion of something different I can look at that may help me determine an end time for some of these actions?

Comment: How are you executing those actions?  Are you using COM to control these application?  Or are you taking these actions manually, with your mouse?

Comment: You should check out psutil, https://pypi.org/project/psutil/ there might be something useful there

Comment: @TimRoberts I believe I can use COM for apps like Excel but I was under the impression that I can't for Power BI and Tableau. So for those 2 I just manipulate the GUI by sending keyboard presses. If there is a better way to do it for those 2 I am all ears. :)

Comment: @Nin17 I looked at it a little but didn't see that it would show me the Operation of a process/thread but I will take a deeper look just in case.

Comment: If you're using COM, then it's obvious when an action is finished -- the API returns.  If you are forcing keystrokes, then it is your ugly responsibility to figure out something to watch for to tell you when the operation is complete.  To be honest, it would be easier to use the stopwatch on your smart phone.

Comment: @TimRoberts I agree but that's not an option as I am trying to automate the timing of the actions. Part of my problem is that both Power BI Desktop and Tableau Desktop integrate with Python so you can use Python to import data, create visuals, etc. When I try to search for automating either of those with Python I get a sea of articles/posts about the integration stuff and not what I am looking for.